# What is the best way to compare data when importing to database?

Tags: php, mysql, algorithm, levenshtein-distance

I have a MySQL database table containing information on around 1000 shops. Now I will be importing more shops through uploading an Excel spread sheet, and I am trying to avoid duplicates.

- Shops may have the same name, but never the same address.
- Shops may have the same address, but never the same name

But here is my problem.

- Stores may be misspelled
- Address may be misspelled

Currently I'm importing the data to a temporary table. Now I'm wondering what is the best approach for comparing the imported shops with the ones already existing.

My plan is to go through each row and compare the shops.

- First compare a.name = b.name AND a.street = b.street. On match, shop is deleted.
- Then I will do a Levenshtein comparison on name and street. Here I probably will have to manually look at the results to determine if it's a duplicate.

Does anyone have experince with this sort of data comparison?

**Update**
Thanks for good answers.

Fields that will be used for comparison are:

- name
- street address
- zip code
- city
- Country

I'm thinking something along these lines:

Select rows where name = Lavenshtein and country = country.
That way I only have to work with a small list.

Then I can start comparing name and address more thoroughly.

Answer (score 4):

Levenshtein-distance is the way to do it, and you can avoid manual input. But the actual implementation will depend on some sort of prior knowledge about the data. Like how much error do you expect in the spellings.

Suppose for example its a good quality data, and you only expecting typos, you can generate a matching condition based on, 1) are number of words same? 2) sequence of those words 3) A small threshold on allowed  error in Levenshtein-distance for each word in the name.

The conditions can be reinforced, by checking against address with similar condition when there is ambiguity in name or visa-versa.

Comment: Levenshtein is a good way to go, as Shaunak says. Also consider stripping out "noise" words and converting abbreviations to the same word. I've done comparisons of company names before, and the comparisons work a lot better if (for British companies, for example) you strip out "the", "Limited", "Ltd", convert all "Co" to "Company", "UK" to "United Kingdom", "1ST" to "FIRST", etc. before the Levenshtein. You'll get more of a feel for what your data needs as you start out -- just putting all the shop names in an ordered list will give you some hints.

Answer (score 3):

To expand on my comment to Shaunak's answer, the approach I took when I did this was:

Make a series of "hashes" of each name, in priority order. For example, for a bunch of financial companies in the UK, I used the following:

- "Hash" 1: The exact company name, e.g. "St. John & James' Financial Investments Ltd.".
- Hash 2: The company name, with all non-alphanumeric characters stripped out and spaces normalised: "St John James Financial Investments Ltd"
- Hash 3: Common abbreviations expanded, e.g. "1st" to "First", "Ltd" to "Limited": "Saint John James Financial Investments Limited". I also did common misspellings here, e.g. "Independant" to "Independent". Your common misspellings will obviously depend on your source data.
- Hash 4: "Stop" words, e.g. "The", "Limited", removed: "Saint John James Financial Investments".

I shoved all those into a table, then built a query to compare each company name in the table with all the others, based on them matching on hash 1, hash 2, hash 3, hash 4. That gave me a confidence factor -- the higher the number of matched hashes, the more likely it was that the companies were actually the same. (Note that with the approach I took, if hash 1 matches, hashes 2, 3 and 4 are guaranteed to match, and so on down the line.)

(Check for empty hashes, too, and ignore -- "The Limited Company" could reduce to an empty hash, but you don't want it matching other empty hashes.)

I used this approach along with Levenshtein to filter my possible duplicates into likelihood order -- how you work out where to fit this possible approach in with Levenshtein will depend on your data; you might want to apply Levenshein to the third hash rather than the actual name, for example -- and present a list of possible duplicates to my business people to make the final decision, having automatically matched the highest-confidence matches where I was sure the names really represented the same company.

Looking at my code, I also used a hash that was a [Soundex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundex) conversion of each word after stripping stop words, etc, though my comments note that [Metaphone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaphone) would have been better (I was using SQL Server, so Soundex was built in...)

Comment: Thanks for a thourough answer. I don't have to worry about "noise" words, as shops normally don't have that - only the company that owns the shop. And if a shop is called '2nd hand', then I can't change that to 'Second hand' :)  I've never used hash before, so I'm not sure how this works. I did find this link, which I hope I can use: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/539816/steps-in-implementing-hashtable-in-php-and-mysql

Comment: I was using the word "hash" quite loosely -- that's just a word I'm using to describe the "slimmed down" names. How much fiddling your names need might even depend on your source; all my data was typed in by people in my company after phone calls, so it wouldn't have surprised me to find a shop called both "2nd Hand" and "Second Hand" being the same shop. Or "Body Shop" and "The Body Shop", say... Really, in this case, your approach is going to be governed by your data, and it's only by getting started that you're going to be able to set your exact direction, I'd say.

Comment: Yup, I'll use the method I use the most. Try and fail :)

Comment: @MattGibons, do you know the performance of these types of controlls? Let's say I'm checking 100 street names up against a DB with 1000 street names.